# How great a Quidditch player was Madam Hooch?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

[Madam Rolanda Hooch](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Rolanda_Hooch) was a strict but caring witch who worked as the Flying instructor, Quidditch referee and coach at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry

Are there any canon sources (from the books/Pottermore/JKR) which helps infer Madam Hooch's capabilities and competencies as a Quidditch player?

Did she play for any international Quidditch team? What team at Hogwarts did she represent in her school days, and what was her position and how good a player was she?

Comment: I've always wondered, is "Madam Hooch" as funny sounding to Brits as it is to Americans?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai That seems impossible to answer; as long as it sounds funny to both, how would one know which group finds it relatively funnier on average?

Comment: Well it's about five funny sounding to Americans. How much is it to Brits?

Comment: 5 humor units. (1 humor unit == 6.022140 humour units)

Comment: Anyway that I can improve on [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116937/55866)?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I never got these Imperial Units. How much is it in milliChaplin?

Comment: About 13 montyPythons

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Unknown.

From [HP Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Rolanda_Hooch), sourced to *Quidditch Through the Ages*:

> Sometime between her graduation and her return to Hogwarts, Rolanda was selected by the Department of Magical Games and Sports as the Hogwarts Quidditch referee, and underwent a series of complicated and rigorous tests, both written and practical.

So she was Ministry-approved as a Hogwarts teacher. This doesn't say whether she was chosen because of a stellar career as a professional Quidditch player, but the fact that she had to go through so many tests suggests that she *hadn't* already proved herself in the field.

Besides, look at real life. **How many professional sporting stars go on to become boarding school PE teachers?** It doesn't really sound very realistic, does it?

Whether she was on her House's Quidditch team at Hogwarts is also unknown, but seems likely. Which House she was in is also unknown.

As a bonus (though not really relevant), here's the only thing about Madam Hooch that I've been able to discover in any [JKR interview](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/12/23/transcript-of-part-1-of-pottercast-s-jk-rowling-interview):

> I know a few people out there had been wondering if Madam Hooch had ever been in love.
>
> **JKR:** *(laughs)* You know what? Madam Hooch really did not have any kind of romantic backstory. Well, not of my invention. We’ll have to go and trawl the fanfic for that.

Comment: I agree, I see her as a typical Physical Education teacher, someone who was into sports, and had understanding to teach the basics and could train and drill students, and thus chose it as a career. She might have been a very good educator as well, having a good hand with the children (strictness and discipline isn't necessarily out of meanness), lending to the Ministry choosing as a candidate for the position. Along those lines, my Soccer coach in HS was an ex-Marine, drilled us every day, and had a good team in our division to show for it.

Comment: "Besides, look at real life. How many professional sporting stars go on to become boarding school PE teachers?"

Former Arsenal player [Steve Gatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Gatting) taught football at [Chirst's Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ%27s_Hospital)

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitgift_School#Sport  "Whitgift has a number of former sporting professionals currently coaching at the school. These include the former Surrey cricketer David Ward, Colin Pates the former Chelsea and Arsenal defender, Neil Kendrick, the former Surrey spin bowler, and Steve Kember, the former Palace and Chelsea midfielder and manager at Selhurst Park." And Hogwarts seems to be very prestigious place to work in magical Britain.

Answer (score 13):

From *Prisoner of Azkaban*:

> “Look at the balance on  it! If the  Nimbus series has a fault, it’s a slight  list  to  the tail  end — you often  find they develop a  drag  after a  few years.  They’ve updated the  handle  too, a bit slimmer than the Cleansweeps, **reminds me of the old Silver Arrows — a pity they’ve stopped making  them. I learned to  fly on one**,  and a very  fine old broom it was too. . . .”
>
> She continued in this  vein for some time, until Wood said, “Er — Madam Hooch?  Is it okay  if  Harry has the Firebolt back? We need  to  practice. . . .”

While I wouldn't consider this canon, the GBA video game of *The Philosopher's Stone* has a line from Madam Hooch:

> A spell! I haven't been this annoyed since my broom was singed by overzealous anti-aircraft during the Great War!

We can probably assume that she was a skilled Quidditch player from the fact that she referees, teaches flying lessons, and is consulted by McGonagall about broomstick magic:

> “It will need to be checked for jinxes,” said Professor McGonagall. “Of course, I’m no expert, but I daresay  Madam Hooch and Professor Flitwick will  strip it down —”

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :)  But, that only talks about her learning stages, right? How can I infer her Quidditch skills from that? [Confession:  My doubt has stemmed from that very part of the book :) ]

Comment: @Dawny33 While the quotes do not prove her Quidditch skills, they do give the impression that she is a skilled broom flyer (given the implication that she participated in broom-mounted combat) and has knowledge of and interest in professional brooms akin to that of an auto mechanic in regards to high-performance cars.

Comment: My comment applies equally well to the question itself anyway, so no problem there.